# A question about eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $v=\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\\v_4\end{pmatrix}$ be a nonzero column vector in $\Bbb R^4$ and let $A=vv^T$. Find the eigenvalues of $A$

There must be a easier way rather than calculate it directly. But I couldn't think of that, could somebody help me? Many thanks

Comment: What if you tried $v = (v_1, v_2)$ instead? Do you see the pattern from the much smaller $2x2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eigenvalues are $\{\|v\|^2, 0, 0, 0\}$.  Consider

$$Av = (vv^T)v = v (v^Tv) = v \|v\|^2 = v\lambda .$$

So we conclude $v$ is an eigenvector and $\|v\|^2$ is an eigenvalue.

Now consider the mutually orthogonal $u_1$, $u_2$, $u_3$ such that $\mathrm{span}(u_1, u_2, u_3) \perp v$, then

$$Au_i = (vv^T)u_i = v (v^Tu_i) =0 = v\lambda .$$

So we likewise conclude that $u_1$, $u_2$, $u_3$  are engenvectors with eigenvalues of $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for some vector $ w $, $ A w = v ( w \cdot v) $. If you choose an orthonormal basis $ \{ e_1 = \frac{v}{|v|}, e_2, e_3,e_4 \} $, then is it easier?